# find a symbol from the text array and if next element is also a symbol, push both of them

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a **text** array and a **symbols** and current code do this : search in the **text** array and if there is an element of the **symbols** array in the **text** array, push it in a new array **(coinsArr)**

I want to find a symbol from the text array and if next element is also a symbol, push both of them(the current symbol and the element and the next element, which is also a symbol)with one / between them.

So this is my code:

```js
const text = [
  'aaaa', 'BTC',
  '08', '324',
  'ETH', '233',
  'yyyy', '30000',
  'XRP', 'xxxxxGG',
  'llll', '546',
  'BCH', 'LTC',
  'xxxyyy', '435',
  'XLM', 'DASH',
  'COIN'
];

const symbols = ['XLM', 'XTZ', 'BTC', 'DASH', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'BNB', 'BCH', 'XRP'];


const coinsArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < symbols.length; j++) {
    const el = symbols[j];
    if (el == text[i]) {
      coinsArr.push(el);
    }
  }
}
console.log({
  'coinsArr': coinsArr
});
```

And gives this output(just search in text array and find symbols) :

```
['BTC','ETH','XRP','BCH','LTC','XLM','DASH','COIN']
```

But I want this output :

```
['BCH/LTC','XLM/DASH']
```

Comment: what about `DASH/COIN`?

Comment: Oh yes I forgot it

Comment: I edited , `COIN` isn't in symbols array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and optimise the access of `symbols` using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const text = [
  'aaaa', 'BTC',
  '08', '324',
  'ETH', '233',
  'yyyy', '30000',
  'XRP', 'xxxxxGG',
  'llll', '546',
  'BCH', 'LTC',
  'xxxyyy', '435',
  'XLM', 'DASH',
  'COIN'
];

const symbols = ['XLM', 'XTZ', 'BTC', 'DASH', 'ETH', 'LTC', 'BNB', 'BCH', 'XRP'];

const set = new Set(symbols);

const result = text.reduce((acc, curr, i, src) => {
  const next = src[i + 1];
  if (set.has(curr) && set.has(next)) acc.push(`${curr}/${next}`);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Have a look, Answer is edited...

Comment: thanks , but if the three symbols were repeated in a row , How can I return only the first two?

Comment: show me an example. Then I might help you

Comment: `text = ['aaaa', 'BTC', '08', '324', 'LTC', 'XLM', 'DASH']` and here are three symbols in a row( LTC , XLM , DASH ) , we want this output : `['LTC/XLM']` but your code gives this output : `['LTC/XLM' , 'XLM/DASH']`

Comment: @dumpAndDie I'd love to help but, would you mind if you could add another question. Because there might be someone who will face same problem like you did. So answering two question in one question won't be good and not recommended by stackoverflow community. 